# How to get Mozilla Firefox to show file download progress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firefox

My MVC application has a simple file download controller action that downloads a file.

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Download(string fileId, string filename)
{
    //var fullFilePath = FileService.GetFullPath(fileId); // get the path to file
    var fullFilePath = fileId;
    return File(fullFilePath, "application/octet-stream", filename);
}
```

I can download/save files successfully but can't seem to get Firefox to show the file download progress. All other browsers shows the file download progress.

Does anyone know how to get Mozilla Firefox to show the file download progress?

Comment: Assuming the files are downloading fine I doubt this problem is server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `Content-Length` to the header so the browser can calculate that.

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
```

Comment: @user1204195, you can add that line right before your `return File` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send a `Content-Length` header that tells the size of the file in bytes, otherwise the browser has no idea how large the file is and it cannot display a progress bar.

If you pass a content-length, then it can display a progress bar as it downloads.